# VoiceOver in iOS7 can't read HTML <input type="date"> component

Tags: ios7, datepicker, accessibility, voiceover

Voiceover in iOS7 can't read type="date" input component, but this component can be read by iOS 5 and 6 voiceover.

Is it iOS7 bug?

Comment: Possibly. It looks like UIPickerViews have some VoiceOver bugs in iOS 7. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21005119/how-do-i-support-voiceover-in-uipickerview-on-an-ipad-running-an-iphone-only-app